# c# razor - If condition for sql based on request data

Tags: c#, razor

What's the proper syntax for using an if statement with my sql server query in c# razor? I want to run my query based on the month received.

Here's what I've tried without success. The if (selectedMonth == "June" ) is not being satisfied.

```
var db = Database.Open("DATABASENAME");
var selectedYear = Request["year"];
var selectedMonth = Request["month"];

if (selectedMonth == "June" ) {
    var sql_finGoal = @"SELECT ID, Goal, Month From [DATABASENAME].[dbo].[mpr_fin_goals]
    WHERE UserName = @0 and Year= @1 and Month= @2"; 
    var finGoal = db.Query(sql_finGoal, windowsUser, selectedYear, selectedMonth); 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Here's what I've tried without success` this is not a technical description of a problem

Comment: Why are you running database queries inside View-level (Razor) code? You shouldn't do that because Views should only be concerned with the _display_ of information and not with how it was obtained.

Comment: Do you mean the line `if (selectedMonth == "June" )` is not being satisfied that is why your query is not executed? Kindly give us more details about your question. This will help us to gain insight of what is your problem.

Comment: Yes Jeric, if (selectedMonth == "June" ) is not being satisfied

Comment: The razor code only gets executed when the view is initialized anyway. Like @Dai says, the view is not for this. Instead have a view action either trigger a controller request or do an Ajax call via JavaScript.

Comment: Ok thanks for the comments. I will take a different approach to my problem.